# Hidden Trivia Question 01

Tags: knowledge

The steps of the Parisian tower and the leaning tower are the the steps to use in the question.

When the oracle nodded affirmatively, it was only at this point that the Emperor agreed. The eternal empire would state to its enemies that it was once again building towards greatness. It had previously built its success on the relationship between the emperor and the oracle and would do so once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden trivia question can first of all be found by noting that...

> ...'the Parisian tower' (i.e. the [Eiffel Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower)) has **1665 steps**, and the ['Leaning Tower' of Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa) has **296 steps**.
>
>  Now use these numbers by taking the first word (the '1' in 1665) then counting on 6 words, then 6 again, 5, 2, 9 and 6 to produce the question: *When was the empire state building built?*

Now answer it!

> The [Empire State Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_State_Building) was built from 1930 to 1931. Construction started on March 17, 1930, and the building opened thirteen and a half months later on May 1, 1931.

In situ (see bolded words below):

> **When** the oracle nodded affirmatively, it **was** only at this point that **the** Emperor agreed. The eternal **empire** would **state** to its enemies that it was once again **building** towards greatness. It had previously **built** its success on the relationship between the emperor and the oracle and would do so once again.

Comment: nice :) I never thought of that, but I agree with your logic

Answer (score -2):

There are 1665 steps from the esplanade up to the top of the Parisian Tower, another name for the Eiffel Tower, and the Leaning Tower of Pisa has 296 or 294 steps since the seventh floor has two fewer steps on the north-facing staircase.

When I hear the word "Oracle", I think of the Oracle of Delphi, but

The Eternal Empire, also known colloquially as the Empire of Zakuul, was a government based on Zakuul led by Emperor Valkorion sometime before the Galactic War that Valkorion sought to use to reshape the entire galaxy.

That would fit in the "Eternal Empire" and "Emperor" parts...

Comment: This is NOT a final answer, since I cannot go farther on this logic, but maybe these would help someone smarter find the true answer